matching numpy conditions row and column without iteration
Given a dataframe condition defined as:
0    [3, 4]
1       [2]

I want another dataframe's 0th row, column 3 and 4 and 1th row, column 2 to be set to 0
For example given another dataframe df2:
        1         2       3         4  
0  0.275464  0.275404  0.2782  0.273485  
1  0.275464  0.275404  0.2782  0.273485 

After applying condition, I want df2 to become:
        1         2       3         4  
0  0.275464  0.275404  0.0000  0.0000  
1  0.275464  0.000000  0.2782  0.273485 

Is there a good way to do this without iterating over the individual rows?

When you talk about dataframes, are you meaning Pandas dataframes, or are you just working entirely with numpy arrays? If the former, you should add the pandas tag to the question.

@MattPitkin yep pandas dataframes. edited

What type is your condition? Is it numpy array?

A possible solution, which:

Creates a 2D numpy array with the wanted indices (it subtracts 1 to align column names with column indices).
Creates a boolean mask to select the wanted elements of df.
Assigns 0 to the wanted elements of df.

The dataframe cond was created as follows:
cond = pd.DataFrame({
    '0':    [[3, 4]],
    '1':       [[2]]

})

cond = cond.T

The solution:
indices = cond.explode(0).reset_index().astype(int).values - 1
mask = np.full(df.shape, False)
mask[indices[:, 0] + 1, indices[:, 1]] = True
df.values[mask] = 0

Output:
          1         2       3         4
0  0.275464  0.275404  0.0000  0.000000
1  0.275464  0.000000  0.2782  0.273485


You create indices, but it doesn't seem to be used in the answer.

Thanks, @MattPitkin! My fault when pasting my solution. Fixed now.

Use MultiLabelBinarizer for mask and set 0 for 1 values:
np.random.seed(2023)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(2,6)))
print (df)
          0         1         2         3         4         5
0  0.321988  0.890422  0.588052  0.126596  0.141341  0.467896
1  0.022090  0.727275  0.524387  0.544935  0.456373  0.501382

condition = pd.Series([[3,4],[2]])

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
mask = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(condition),columns=mlb.classes_).eq(1)
print (mask)
       2      3      4
0  False   True   True
1   True  False  False

df[mask] = 0
print (df)
          0         1         2         3         4         5
0  0.321988  0.890422  0.588052  0.000000  0.000000  0.467896
1  0.022090  0.727275  0.000000  0.544935  0.456373  0.501382


You can also do in this way:
condition = [[3,4],[2]]
condition_flatten = pd.Series(condition).explode().astype(int)
rows = condition_flatten.index
cols = condition_flatten.values
df2.values[rows, cols] = 0


You can do also this way:
condition = [[3,4],[2]]

rows = []
cols = []
for i, items in enumerate(condition):
    rows.extend([i]*len(items))
    cols.extend(items)
    
df2.values[rows, cols] = 0

